# Check if title exists in wordpress database before import

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a json feed to import new posts. This works as expected, but I am not able to prevent importing duplicated posts. When I run the script twice it also imports the posts twice.

How can I check the wordpress database to prevent importing the same posts.

```
require_once("wp-load.php");

$url = 'https://somejsonfeed.com'; // path to the JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$flights = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed

foreach ($flights['response'] as $item) {
$title = $item['flight']['iata_number'];

    // Check if already exists

     if ( get_page_by_title( $title ) == null ) {
        // Insert post
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_content' => $title,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'post'
        );
        // Insert post
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        // Insert post meta if available
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value' );

        // Uncomment to check if meta key is added
        // $get_meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', true );
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($get_meta_value);
    }
}else{
    // Update meta value
    update_post_meta($get_page->ID, 'my_key', 'meta_value');

    // Uncomment to check if meta key is added
    // $get_meta_value = get_post_meta( $get_page->ID, 'meta_key', true );
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($get_meta_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the code below

```
require wp-load.php to use built-in WordPress functions
require_once("wp-load.php");

$url = 'https://somejsonfeed.com'; // path to the JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$flights = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed

foreach ($flights['response'] as $item) {
$title = $item['flight']['iata_number']; 

if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
}
  // change custom-post-name in post type
  if ( get_page_by_title( $title, OBJECT, 'custom-post-name' ) == null ) {
    // Insert post
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $title,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    // Insert post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    // Insert post meta if available
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value' );

    // Uncomment to check if meta key is added
    // $get_meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', true );
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($get_meta_value);
}
}else{
// Update meta value
update_post_meta($get_page->ID, 'my_key', 'meta_value');

// Uncomment to check if meta key is added
// $get_meta_value = get_post_meta( $get_page->ID, 'meta_key', true );
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($get_meta_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What works well for me is `post_exists($title)`. Returns the post ID, so in your code, I would use

```
$current_post_id = post_exists($title);
if( 0 === $current_post_id) {
    `enter code here`add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value' );
}
```

One thing I notice is that you have:
'meta_key', 'meta_value', so of course, I copied that part, but you would need to replace whatever meta_key and meta_value.

I hope this helps.

Bruce

Comment: Tried the code, but get the following error
`Call to undefined function post_exists() in /www/wp-content/themes/generatepress/test2.php:46`

Comment: Fixed the error by adding `if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
    }` Still inserting the same post